# Create an linked Table from an ADODB.Connection in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access

How can I create an linked Table in Ms Access 2016 with an existing ADODB.Connection Object?

The connection object is connected to a PostgreSQL DB, but I hope this does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Tables can either be linked to ODBC data sources or specific ISAM data sources.

You can't link tables to ADODB connection objects or OLEDB data sources.

Comment: However, if the `ADODB.Connection` object is for an ODBC connection it might be possible to create an ODBC linked table by retrieving the connection string from the `ConnectionString` property of the `ADODB.Connection` object, prefixing it with `"ODBC;"` and using it as part of a VBA `DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, ...` statement.

Comment: You have two connections to the Database, if you do so.

Comment: If connections are the issue, you can work with existing ADODB connections in forms and reports, though. Just not tables. You can use datasheet forms to get a very table-like experience.